# mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user | Acceso 127.0.0.1 con un nuevo usuario en PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost, conexión

Para usos didácticos, estoy generando una conexión simple con la database desde el localhost.

```
$server = "127.0.0.1";
$user = "admin";
$pass = "adminwebsite";
$database = "website";

mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $database);
```

Dentro de la database creé un nuevo usuario (*admin*) para establecer la conexión con la database sin tener que utilizar *root*. ***admin*** posee privilegios para acceder únicamente a la database *website*.

El problema que tengo (y que posiblemente se deba a desconocimiento), es que al utilizar este código, el navegador me envía el siguiente mensaje:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

La duda que tengo es la siguiente:

**Cuando se establece una conexión hacia una database en localhost, ¿Es obligatorio que se utilice un superusuario?**

Lo que quiero hacer es generar la conexión hacia la database con un nuevo usuario que solo posea privilegios para el acceso hacia su propia base de datos, y que no pueda acceder a las funciones globales del superusuario. El problema es que al hacerlo el navegador me muestra ese error.

¿Será posible hacer esto en local?, ¿será un error que se deba al hecho de estar trabajando en localhost?, ¿o se debe a la falta de configuración de alguno de los archivos de Apache o Mysql?

Cabe mencionar que al crear un nuevo usuario con privilegios globales (como los del usuario *root*), no me aparece este error.

¿Es posible solucionar este problema?

De antemano, agradezco a quien corresponda.

Comment: Como create al usuario?

Comment: Básicamente es el error actual te dice que es de password. Suele ser por ser incorrecta, llegar vacía por alguna razón. No se donde estas haciendo la prueba, pero te recomendaría que las hagas elevando la seguridad del usuario y la clave. En algunos servidores puede dar este error si la clave es del tipo 12345 para llevarte a obligatoriamente a cambiar por una clave mas fuerte. Podrías pegar en la pregunta los privilegios asignados cuando te da este error ?

Answer (score 0):

al parecer es porque tu usuario no tiene permisos para localhost o no le dijiste al momento de crearlo cual es la base de datos de ese usuario.

verifica que el usuario tenga su base de datos en los permisos